# Symfony2 validation errors in list on top of form

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

I've been breaking my head on the Symfony2.1 form validation. What I want is just a regular  list on top of the form with the errors it contains after validation. An extensive search did not result in the wanted solution.

There are a couple of questions left:

1. How can I globally disable field-specific errors, so errors won't appear aside of the field? I know about the error_bubbling, but it shouldnt be needed to set this for each field.
2. How can I parse all the error in a simple list on top of the form? I know [how to override the Twig templates](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#making-application-wide-customizations), but this does not result in a group of errors that is accessible by the form_errors function

What I found / investigated so far:

1. [Make all form validation errors show up at top in symfony?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034625/make-all-form-validation-errors-show-up-at-top-in-symfony)
2. [Form-wide error_bubbling in Symfony 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10322300/form-wide-error-bubbling-in-symfony-2) > is terrible if you've got more then 4 forms
3. http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html  > does not has the right solution
4. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8216192/1794894 > could be a solution, but is not a nice one

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 methods i can think of for disabling the errors:

1. Hide them with CSS.
2. Override the Twig templates and remove the error output.

As to listing out all the error on the top, that is a bit harder. Best bet would be to pull the list of form fields and loop through them outputting the errors.

Comment: That is what I already have found indeed, is it possible to configure this globally? I don't want to create a loop for all forms manually.